# How to update MySQL Rows using PHP PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is how I am receving data from a page:

```
 $response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=xxxxxx");
    if ($response != FALSE) {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
    }
```

And here is an example of what is inside the page:

```
{

  "genres": [
    {

      "name": "Action"
    },
    {

      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {

      "name": "Science Fiction"
    }
  ]

}
```

Here is how, I Insert the data

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE genres SET genres_name = :genres_name WHERE tmdb_id = :tmdb_id");

    $stmt->bindParam(':tmdb_id', $tmdb_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':genres_name', $genres_name,PDO::PARAM_INT);

if (isset($response["genres"]) && is_array($response["genres"])) 
{
    foreach ($response["genres"] as $genreObject) 
    {
        $genres_name = $genreObject["name"];
        $stmt->execute();
    } 
}
```

**Original Result:**

This is the data it update inside `Genres` table

```
tmdb_id         genres_name
5                Action
5                Action
5                Action
```

Expected Result:

```
tmdb_id         genres_name
5                Action
5                Adventure
5                Science Fiction
```

Comment: update will work on single row every time based on id, since id is 5 so it will always update the same record. I think you want insert

Comment: I was using this code to insert data first, but then I changed it to update..because I need to update the data regularly.

What is the problem here Sir @AlivetoDie

Comment: As long as `$tmdb_id` is unique, there is no problem. Where do you assign `$tmdb_id` and `$genres_name`? It looks like you are doing that just one time.

Comment: the clause WERE tmdb_id = 5 is finding 3 rows with that ID, therefore it updates all 3 of the rows having that id, with the same genre_name. That's how an UPDATE statement works. Do you need the rows to have separate IDs so you can update them with different values?

Comment: I want rows to have same ID, but with different values @ADyson

Comment: you can only edit/update a row with a unique id of row. in database structure it the primary key.

Comment: why would you want that? Then you can't use an ID to tell them apart, which is the whole point of an ID. The fact that you've given them the same ID is the exact reason you've got this problem. What's the reason for giving them all the same ID? What benefit is it giving you?