# How to update rows with same ID but different values in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My table named `genres`is something like this:

```
tmdb_id         genres_name
5                Action
5                Adventure
5                Science Fiction
6                Crime
6                Comedy
```

Now, I want to update this table, but the problem is, my code updates table like this:

```
tmdb_id         genres_name
5                Action
5                Action
5                Action
6                Crime
6                Crime
```

It updates the same value in all rows with the same id. I want different values.

Note: I cannot use Primary Key (auto increment) for some reasons.

Here is my full code:

This is how I am receiving data from a page:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=xxxxxx");
    if ($response != FALSE) {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
    }
```

And here is an example of what is inside the page:

```
{

  "genres": [
    {

      "name": "Action"
    },
    {

      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {

      "name": "Science Fiction"
    }
  ]

}
```

Here is how I Insert the data

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE genres SET genres_name = :genres_name WHERE tmdb_id = :tmdb_id");

    $stmt->bindParam(':tmdb_id', $tmdb_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':genres_name', $genres_name,PDO::PARAM_INT);

if (isset($response["genres"]) && is_array($response["genres"])) 
{
    foreach ($response["genres"] as $genreObject) 
    {
        $genres_name = $genreObject["name"];
        $stmt->execute();
    } 
}
```

Original Result:

This is the data it update inside `Genres` table

```
tmdb_id         genres_name
5                Action
5                Action
5                Action

tmdb_id         genres_name
5                Action
5                Adventure
5                Science Fiction
```

Comment: I think, you should better check about normalization.

Comment: `Note: I cannot use Primary Key (auto increment) for some reasons.` Very funny. Good bye.

Comment: please don't spam SO .instead of posting new post just update your old one . which is you asked 1 hour before .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768731/how-to-update-mysql-rows-using-php-pdo-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

To update any particular row, you need to have key column(s). As you already mentioned that you can't use primary key (auto increment). But, you can have composite key ? where combination of column acts as unique row.

So, you could add `genres_name` column in where clause.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE genres SET genres_name = :genres_name WHERE tmdb_id = :tmdb_id and genres_name = :genres");

$stmt->bindParam(':tmdb_id', $tmdb_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':genres_name', $genres_name,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':genres', $genres_name_to_be_updated,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```